# Reset/Reinitialize jQuery unobtrusive validation for dynamic AJAX-forms to clear old validation rules

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 in combination with the client-side validation and forms in modal dialogs loaded via AJAX.
This all works fine, BUT if I open and post a lot of these dialogs/forms without reloading the page each submit gets slower and slower, because of (at least I think) the validation is still trying to validate all the past forms, and this takes some time. I come to that conclusion because I have a "Loading..." indicator which appears as soon as the submit begins and the time between clicking submit until the indicator is showing up is increasing from submit to submit.

**Is there a way to completely reinitialize the client-side validation to avoid this problem?**

I already searched a lot, but with all the terms I could imagine I only found solutions to clear/reinitialize the "one form" on screen...

I do not use any special code, just default MVC forms (simplified):

```
@model MyModel

@section Scripts {  
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")  
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post,
             new { id = "MyForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyValue)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyValue)
    <input type="submit" class="my-class" value="@Resources.Submit" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#MyForm').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($('#MyForm').valid()) {
                var formValues = $('#MyForm').serialize();
                $.post("@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")", formValues, function (result) {
                    if (result.startsWith("OK")) {
                        formValueHasChanged = false;
                        closeOverlay();
                    } else {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

With a model like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(RequiredAttribute), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Content))]
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

And such forms are loaded multiple times on the same page, as it is the edit-dialog for list items and it is opened once for each item edited.

**UPDATE:** I now did some profiling using Chrome DevTools to confim its the validation causing the lags:
[image: Profiling]

Comment: Why are you validating a whole page of forms at once?  Where is the code?

Comment: @Sparky There is nothing special about the code, please see my edit...

Comment: *"I only found solutions to clear/reinitialize the "one form" on screen"* - did you try this same solution inside of `.each()` so you can do all forms at once?  `$('form').each(function() { $(this).....`

Comment: @Sparky The other forms do not exist anymore, as the "overlay-container" is replaced after each AJAX call